# The preservation of the injectivity of maps

Tags: functions

Suppose $f$ and $g$ are injective maps such that $h \circ f = g $. What are the requirements on $h$?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Denoting by $Im(f)$ the image of the map $f$, the only requirement you need on $h$ is that $h$ is defined at least on $Im(f)$ and injective on this set.

Answer (score 0):

Well, $h$ must be defined as $g\circ f^{-1}$ on the image of $f$. Elsewhere, it may be anything.